What software backs up Mobile Documents with "optimized storage" on? and where are the iCloud Photos stored if not there?
This is a bit of an update as well as a question.  It seems in the past that the only way to backup the iCloud files in the ~/Library/Mobile Documents folder was to have one Mac where "optimized storage" was turned off, and then use a normal backup program like Time Machine to backup that folder on that computer.
But now CCC (Carbon Copy Cloner) has a system to be able to download the files for backup, and compare the checksums of undownloaded files so that if they haven't changed they don't need to be redownloaded for an incremental backup. So that's the update.
My question is, does any other software do this? Or is it just CCC?  I rely on Time Machine for most of the computers in my fleet, CCC is only deployed a few select ones. In testing it does not look like iCloud will make any effort to backup files that are not there due to "optimized storage".  In fact the entire Mobile Documents folder seems empty in my Time Machine backups.
My second question is there any similar process for iCloud Photos?  That is, is there a way to compared the iCloud Photos checksum of a file to the backup copy, and only download it if it's changed?  I can't find any equivalent location to "Mobile Documents" for the iCloud photos.
